# How to fix powershell core New-Object fail for EPPlus assembly loaded with Add-Type

Tags: .net-core, epplus, powershell-core

In powershell core 6.2 I add the EPPlus assembly using Add-Type and try to instantiate an object of a type defined in the assembly using New-Object.  Even though I've confirmed the assembly loaded OK, the instantiation fails.

I can instantiate some of the types in the loaded assembly e.g. OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat.  The type I most want to instantiate (OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage) fails.  I have confirmed that the assembly is dotnet core and the type has a default constructor.

Load assembly using:

`Add-Type -AssemblyName 'C:\Users\lorimer1\.nuget\packages\epplus\4.5.3.1\lib\netstandard2.0\EPPlus.dll'`

Confirm Assembly loaded:

`$asm = [appdomain]::currentdomain.GetAssemblies() | Where-Object Location -match 'EPPLus'`

I can instantiate ExcelTextFormat successfully:

`$format = new-object -TypeName OfficeOpenXml.ExcelTextFormat`

But instantiating ExcelPackage fails:

`$test = New-Object -TypeName OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage`

Error Message:

```
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "0" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified."
```

I confirmed declared constructors:

`DeclaredConstructors       : {Void .ctor(), Void .ctor(System.IO.FileInfo), Void .ctor(System.IO.FileInfo, System.String), Void .ctor(System.IO.FileInfo, System.IO.FileInfo)…}`

Edit: I cloned the epplus project from GitHub and found that the ExcelPackage class inside epplus dll has a dependency on Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration ... it seems Add-Type does not resolve dependencies and load them.  There is a -ReferencedAssemblies option but that would require one to know in advance what assemblies are required.  If many are required, the Add-Type command could become rather large.  Does anyone know how to determine dependencies for the dll and load them.  I assume here that all dependencies are part of dotnet core (not custom assemblies).

Comment: Try running in x86 PowerShell because if you have a 32 bit version of Office (the typical install) it may not be able to load it.

Comment: @HAL9256 in this case office is not required.  The purpose of the epplus assembly is to interact with an excel document directly.  An xlsx file is just a zip of xml content so nothing special required.  But I can confirm that I can't use powershell 6.2 for COM object connection to office apps as core does not support office interop yet.